# How to install two mysql instance on same machine

Tags: mysql, database

I want to run two MySQL instances on the same machine.
The reason behind this is, I will be needing two databases with entirely different configurations.

The specifics of the configuration of the both the DB are as follows,

1. Fault tolerant, high-intensity IOPS, RAID 10.
2. Highly available, Low-intensity IOPS, RAID 1.

This two instance will have separate HA policies.

Currently, I am only installing once and running the first instance using systemdctl whereas I am running the second instance manually using separate cnf files.

So now,  how can I install and run two separate instances of MySQL on same machine?

DO I need to create separate instances of the MySQL-server binaries for both instances? 
And do I need to install MySQL-server RPM for a second time into an alternate folder?

If yes, then how?
I also want to understand the implication of using the single binary for running two instances. Does it affect the other instance in any way during recovery process or any other db intensive task?

Comment: Do you need them to run on the same (logical) machine? My first suggestion would be to create separate VMs to facilitate these two databases.

Comment: @DrIvol, Yes they both will run in same logical machines.

Comment: Yes you can do all that. Have a look at [Managing MySQL Server with systemd](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html). Although this question (or at least follow up questions) probably better fits on a different stackexchange-site.

Comment: @Solarflare,
Thanks for the link, let me go thru it and see if this satisfies my need.

Comment: @Solarflare, This feature is available from 5.7.7, whereas I am using 5.6.34(latest in 5.6x)

Comment: While you could still use `systemd` (you would just have to do your configuration manually), for 5.6 the default way is to use `mysqld_safe` to [Run Multiple MySQL Instances on One Machine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-unix-servers.html).